# How can I flatten this UV island out like the example shown? (Flatten UVs)

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

Trying to unwrap this island on the left like the one on the right. Any suggestions?

[image]

This is after adding some more seams but im still not sure how to straighten it out.

[image]

I've figured out how to do this manually by using the tex tools plugin to 'rectify' the island before adding the extra seams in the previous photo.

Pinning the bottom two rows of vertices and than adding the extra seams back that split the top row apart.

[image]

This seems like a very convoluted way to go about this, is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

You could mark these seams, choose the front view and unwrap with the *Cylinder Projection* option:

[image]

In the *UV Editor*, select the top edges and switch the *Pivot* to *Individual Origins*:

[image]

Scale the edges and move them down and you have the desired result:

[image]